# to count the number of pages in a word document in php

Tags: php

How to count the number of pages in a ms word document using php??

i tried this following code but the problem is whenever i reload the file, the word document gets opened automatically.... could someone help me with this ??

```
<?php 

$filename="filepath";
$wdStatisticPages = 2;
   $word = new COM("Word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
   $word->Documents->Open($filename );
   $num_pages = $word->ActiveDocument->ComputeStatistics( $wdStatisticPages );
   echo $num_pages;
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gets opened automatically"?

Comment: it means whenever i try loading the php file... the word file gets opened in the ms word window.. i just want to count the pages in the document without opening the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not going to work without a Word window opening.
COM is a layer on top of RPC (Remote Procedure Call). So it's only a means of sending messages back and forth between PHP and another application (Word in your case).

In order for this communication to happen Word obviously needs to be opened.
It cannot run in the background as a service so it opens a window. Calling `$word->Documents->Open($filename );` is like clicking `File -> Open -> "somefile.doc"`.

I hope you also understand that the Word application instance that you are sending messages to runs on the server, not on the client.

Comment: Thnks fo ur valuable answr... Could u pls tell me a another way to fix it ? Pls....

Comment: I think you could read the discussions on the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797362/programatically-get-pages-count-in-microsoft-word-documents-on-linux (The summary is that there is no standard way of rendering a .doc so there is no standard way of counting the pages. It all depends on how you render them. But MS Word does save a precalculated value)

Comment: open the file and do a Regex search for "nofpages(\d+)": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797362/programatically-get-pages-count-in-microsoft-word-documents-on-linux#answer-1877523